# Service not injected in ActionListener

Tags: jsf, actionlistener, cdi

I'm having a problem regarding actionlistener in my project. I'm creating a website but my problem is at the login and I'm using composite and JSF. Whenever I try to login I get a nullpointer pointing at the actionlistener class line 30 which is in the if statement.

ActionListener class

```
public class LoginActionListener implements ActionListener {  
   @Inject private Service service;  
   @Override  
    public void processAction(ActionEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {  
      UIComponent container = event.getComponent().getNamingContainer();  
      String username = (String) ((UIInput)  
         container.findComponent("form:username")).getValue();  
      String pwd = (String) ((UIInput)  
         container.findComponent("form:password")).getValue();  
      if(service.isRegistered(username, pwd))  
          return;  

      FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
      context.addMessage(container.getClientId(),
         new FacesMessage("Username and password are invalid. Please try again."));
      throw new AbortProcessingException("Invalid credentials");
    }
}
```

Service class

```
public boolean isRegistered(String username, String password){    
for (User u : users) {  
        if (u.getUserName().equals(username) && u.getPassword().equals(password))  
            return true;  
    }  
    return false;  
}
```

Composite login xhtml file
http://blg.nikonsrc.com/image/4nEwBZn2a6VnBoCaET-wUiU_iwnRwLBaMfMR67ypIKVyameRSjNcbAmtoKug6n4_PWUXZcEFpp8/item.JPG?rot=0

http://blg.nikonsrc.com/image/4nEwBZn2a6VnBoCaET-wUiU_iwnRwLBaMfMR67ypIKU7KIV8XlnDFQmtoKug6n4_PWUXZcEFpp8/item.JPG?rot=0

Best regards
Jakob

Comment: What a strange approach. Why not using a normal managed bean with two properties and a normal action method?

Comment: well, this is the way that we have been taught so use it. In our managed bean we have strings, ints etc. and in our service we have create, delete methods. But can u help me with my problem? :)

Comment: I usually don't post answers fixing bad practices, otherwise starters may incorrectly assume that I'd advocate those practices. Ask your tutor instead as s/he appears to know it better.

Answer (score 1):

If your service is null it seems to be a problem with injecting your Service class. Check if the Service class has proper annotations which allows that class to be injected. Be aware that you should use annotations form one package:

For CDI-based bean definitions

```
javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped
javax.inject.Named 
javax.inject.Inject
```

For JSF-based bean definitions

```
javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped
javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean 
javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty
```

For example:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class Service {
    ...
    public boolean isRegistered(String username, String password){
        for (User u : users) {
            if (u.getUserName().equals(username) && u.getPassword().equals(password))
                return true;
        } 
        return false; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Mikolaj.
We have been taught to use the CDI-based bean definitions and my service class is ApplicationScoped and has the right annotations.